# Display ID Number in URL & fetch database results from ID Number into textfields

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm working on a website where I want to display the ID Number on the url as well as fetch its attributes along with it(e.g username, firstname, lastname)

An example would be if I type: **localhost/search/index3.php?u=3**, it would display the database values with it on the page into the textfields.

Here's the codefor my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/search/index3.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

Here's the rest of my code

```html
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database = "ntmadb";

$id = "";
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$username = "";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// connect to mysql database
try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error';
}

// get values from the form
function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();
    $posts[0] = $_POST['id'];
    $posts[1] = $_POST['firstname'];
    $posts[2] = $_POST['lastname'];
    $posts[3] = $_POST['username'];
    return $posts;
}

// Search

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    
    $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $data[0]";
    
    $search_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $search_Query);
    
    if($search_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
            {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                $username = $row['username'];
            }
        }else{
            echo 'No Data For This Id';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Result Error';
    }
}


// Insert
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `members`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `username`) VALUES ('$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
    try{
        $insert_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_Query);
        
        if($insert_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Inserted';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Insert '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}

// Delete
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $delete_Query = "DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `id` = $data[0]";
    try{
        $delete_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $delete_Query);
        
        if($delete_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Deleted';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Deleted';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Delete '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}

// Edit
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $update_Query = "UPDATE `members` SET `firstname`='$data[1]',`lastname`='$data[2]',`username`='$data[3]' WHERE `id` = $data[0]";
    try{
        $update_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $update_Query);
        
        if($update_Result)
        {
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Updated';
            }else{
                echo 'Data Not Updated';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP INSERT UPDATE DELETE SEARCH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="indexx.php?id=" method="post">
            <input type="number" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>"><br><br>
            <div>
                <!-- Input For Add Values To Database-->
                <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
                
                <!-- Input For Edit Values -->
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
                
                <!-- Input For Clear Values -->
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
                
                <!-- Input For Find Values With The given ID -->
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope anyone here can help me set it up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
```

which is for getting "posted" parameters (usually from forms).

You need to be looking at `$_GET['u']` to get the id passed in.

Relevant pages in the manual: [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) ,  [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

---

Edit: just reading through the code, there are a few other bits wrong as the following bits are from an example where a user has posted a form. (ie. the `getPost()` bit). You don't need that if you're trying to get details from a database based on a passed in ID.

---

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
         $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['u']);

         /* execute query */
         $stmt->execute();

         if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
             // Deleted
         } else {
             // Not found / deleted
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Should I remove my `if(isset($_POST['search']))` to` $_GET['u']` ?

Comment: Added an example of code (you may need to edit out bugs). It also uses paremerised queries (safer) but basically says "if there is a parameter "u" in the URL, then build the query, add the parameters and execute.

Comment: Quick question, if using header function in the url will query the data in the page? Thanks for the response.

Comment: They are different things. $_GET queries the URL. the header function adds a header to the HTTP output - you're not there yet.

Comment: I see, I learned how GET and POST differs from each other. Robbie, if you don't mind, What's this piece of code, rather the "i" on it.    `  $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['u']);` ?

Comment: Google 'bind-param mysqli' and read the manual. It's converting the unknown input (it could be anything) into an integer and making it safe so someone can't hack your mysql database. Good practice to start doing now. Also makes your code easier to read and debug.

Comment: Hey bro, thanks for the tips. I am able to call data and display my results in another page. The only problem I'm facing now is getting them to be displayed in my html file. Rather I used another code to trial this. Would you mind helping me out once more? Thanks for everything.