# Insert echo into textfield using Get Method

Tags: php, get

This is a continuation from my previous question "[Display ID Number in URL & fetch database results from ID Number into textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799274/display-id-number-in-url-fetch-database-results-from-id-number-into-textfields/41799459?noredirect=1#comment70826900_41799459)", but dubbed as another one.
*Thanks for helping me out @Robbie. If only I can upvote more :')*

Now for the topic. I can't seem to get to insert the value displayed as an href link into the textfield supposedly I know I'm doing this wrong *obviously since I can't get it to work* I would like some further assistance.

Here are the codes used: index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='get' action="results.php">
<label> What do you like to search for?</label>
<input type='text' name='search'>
<button type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is for the actual php process:

```html
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ntmadb") or die (mysql_error());

$var = "hello";


$clean = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
$hello = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '$clean'") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($hello) >=1)  {
    //getdata
    while($i = mysql_fetch_array($hello)){
        echo '<a href="'.$i['lastname'].'">'.$i['firstname'].'</a>';        
    }

}
else{
    echo "No results found, sorry:(";

}


?>

<html>

<input type='text' name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" ></input></br>
<input type='text' name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" ></input></br>
</html>
```

Thanks alot again

Comment: You appear to be displaying HTML **before** your opening `<html>` tag. Also, `$firstname` and `$lastname` are undefined

Comment: Thank you @Phil for editing my question and code. I simply went up and look for the tutorial on youtube using get method. How would you define them and display them into the textfields? Thank you for helping me out. :)

Comment: What values should they be set to? As for displaying them, you appear to be doing it correctly however I'd go a step further and use `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($firstname) ?>"`

Comment: I'll take note of it. Thank you @Phil. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azuren, you actually gone backwards from your first question ([Display ID Number in URL & fetch database results from ID Number into textfields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799274/display-id-number-in-url-fetch-database-results-from-id-number-into-textfields)) as you've reverted to `mysql_` functions and not `mysqli_` The former (`mysql_`) have been removed from PHP.

I've rewritten using mysqli (roughly - you may need to debug) and answered the question at the same time.

If a tutorial includes any function that begins `mysql_` then find another one!

---

You need to define $firstname and $lastname; I'd suggest doing so as follows:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ntmadb") or die (mysql_error());

$firstname = '';
$lastname = '';

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM members WHERE id = ?")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['search']);

        /* bind result variables */
        $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname );

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($lastname).'">'.htmlspecialchars($firstname).'</a>';
        }

     }
 }
```

}

```
?>
```

Comment: I've noticed that mysql is deprecated but by all means this website I've been working will only be set in a localhost and will never go live. But I'll do take note of it. I'll try out the code you gave. Thank you @Robbie for taking your time in answering. You're awesome!

Comment: Hey man, I'm getting 2 errors on my the code you sent me and gives me this kinds: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in D:\xampp\htdocs\search\results2.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\search\results2.php on line 10. I've included `$id = '';` so that the id will be defined in the following`$stmt` such as this: `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname FROM members WHERE id = '%{id}%'")) {`

Comment: Use your previous code (previous question). You get the connection to mysqli the same way - I just missed that of the answer as it's in the other .